# Comparing dictionary list. TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to compare two sets of data (file1,file2) in a dictionary format. When comparing using **example 1** (see bellow), the code works but when I add more data (**example 2**) I get an error as **tuple indices must be integer or slices**. I'm struggling to understand this, since I'm comparing two sets of dictionaries and not a list to use an integer to compare using integers in the index rather than the name of key in the dictionary.

**#Dict list example 1: with this example, it works**

```
file1= {'name': 'Phill', 'age': 42}
file2= {'name': 'Phill', 'age': 22}
```

**#Dict list example 2: with this example, it doesn't work**

```
file1= {'name': 'Phill', 'age': 42},{'name': 'Phill', 'age': 22}
file2= {'name': 'Phill', 'age': 22},{'name': 'Phill', 'age': 52}

#Function with two args

    def diffValue (file1,file2) :
        

    for newAge in file1,file2 :

        if file1 [ 'age' ] == file2 [ 'age' ] :
            # if no difference found in both files within the age field
            print ( "No difference found" )

        else :

            # the age is different. return values name,age where ever there is a difference from file1 only
            return newAge
```

**Expected results:**

```
Return {'name': 'Phill', 'age': 42},{'name': 'Phill', 'age': 22}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant to do something like this:

```py
file1 = {'name': 'Phill', 'age': 42}, {'name': 'Phill', 'age': 22}
file2 = {'name': 'Phill', 'age': 22}, {'name': 'Phill', 'age': 52}

def diff_value(f1, f2):
    # Create a list to store the differences
    diffs = []

    # Iterate for every element in parallel
    for v1, v2 in zip(f1, f2):
        if v1['age'] == v2['age']:
            # If no difference found in both files within the age field
            print('No difference found')
        
        else:
            # The age is different, append v1 to `diffs`
            diffs.append(v1)
    
    return diffs
    
print(diff_value(file1, file2))
# Output: [{'name': 'Phill', 'age': 42}, {'name': 'Phill', 'age': 22}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> file1= {'name': 'Phill', 'age': 42},{'name': 'Phill', 'age': 22}
>>> file1
({'name': 'Phill', 'age': 42}, {'name': 'Phill', 'age': 22})
>>> type(file1)
<class 'tuple'>
```

file1 is tuple that is why it gives an error

one way to make it work with your function is:

```
def diffValue (file1,file2) :
    for newAge in file1,file2 :
        if file1 [ 'age' ] == file2 [ 'age' ] :
            # if no difference found in both files within the age field
            print ( "No difference found" )
        else :
            # the age is different. return values name,age where ever there is a difference from file1 only
            return newAge
file1= [{'name': 'Phill', 'age': 42},{'name': 'Phill', 'age': 22}]
file2= [{'name': 'Phill', 'age': 22},{'name': 'Phill', 'age': 52}]

a=""
for i in range(len(file1)):
    a+=str(diffValue(file1[i],file2[i]))+","
a=a[:-1]
print(a)
```