# Compare list of dictionaries in different order and multiple Keys

Tags: python-3.x

Following a question I raised in the past on how to compare two sets of dict and return the difference. I had to change that solution because using zip had an issue comparing two sets in parallel, so when ever the list was in a different order, the results were not accurate.

Link to the previous question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68047350/comparing-dictionary-list-typeerror-tuple-indices-must-be-integers-or-slices][1]

I did update the code by using a different method but it was still not accurate enough:

```
f1 = [ { 'name' : 'Phill' , 'status' : 'single' ,'age' : 42 } ,{ 'name' : 'Phill' , 'status' : 'single','age' : 22 } ]
f2 = [ { 'name' : 'Phill' , 'status' : 'single','age' : 22  } , { 'name' : 'Phill' , 'status' : 'single','age' : 52 }]
        
def diff_value (f1 , f2) :
    diffs = [ ]
    for v1 in f1 :
        for v2 in f2 :
            if v1 [ 'age' ] not in v2 [ 'age' ] :
                diffs.append ( v2 )
            else :
                print('no Age difference Found')
    return diffs
```

The code worked better than zip but still not handling the results properly if the order changes, or a new field is added containing age only.

I am looking on how to find the difference based on Age and update the second file with that new age but only if it belongs to the same **Name and Status**.

For example:

```
f1 = [{'name': 'Phill','status':'single','age': 42,}, {'name': 'Phill','status':'single','age': 22}]
f2 = [{'name': 'Phill','status':'single','age': 22,}, {'name': 'Phill','status':'Married','age':52,}]
Output example:
diffs = [{'age': 42}]

f1 = [{'name': 'Phill','status':'single','age': 42,}, {'name': 'Phill','status':'single','age': 22}]
f2 = [{'name': 'Phill','status':'unknown','age': 22,}, {'name': 'Phill','status':'single','age':52}]
 Output example:
diffs = [{'age': 42}]

f1 = [{'name': 'John','status':'single','age': 42,}, {'name': 'Phill','status':'single','age': 22}]
f2 = [{'name': 'Phill','status':'unknown','age': 22,}, {'name': 'Phill','status':'single','age':52},{'name': 'John','status':'single','age':52}]
 Output example:
diffs = [{'age': 42}]
```

I tried adding another loop for each added field I want to compare but it just didn't work.

in my mind, I want to check if Name are the same and status are the same but the age is different then append that age and return as a list
Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you explain your expected output better? How should the `diff_file` work: compare each element in `f1` and `f2` in parallel or compare all elements in `f1` with all elements in `f2`? In case of duplicates in the first file, what should be considered: the first occurrence or the last occurrence? What should the `diff_value` return: only the values that were updated or the whole second file updated?

Comment: output is only the Age return diffs. The script should compare both dictionaries and see if the Names are the same and status are the same but age is different then return the age that is different which should be coming from File one

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code .(Of course, this code fully shows the differences between the two dictionary if you mean it):

```
diff=[]
for v1 in f1:
    for v2 in f2:
        set1 = set(v1.items())
        set2 = set(v2.items())
        dif = set1.difference(set2)
        lst = list(dif)
        dict1 = dict(lst)


        agedict  = {k: v for k, v in dict1.items() if k =='age' and len(dict1)<2}
        if agedict !={}:
            diff.append(agedict)

print(diff)
```

For the output of the second set, the relationship will be as follows:

```
dif = set2.difference(set1)
```

For more information:   [symmetric_difference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.symmetric_difference)

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of this method. This only shows the difference not taking into account, if Names and status are the same then return age if different

Comment: In the edited code of the two sets, if there is a difference, the age will be returned. I hope this is your intention:

Comment: Thanks Sailo, I am still testing the code with different scenarios. Also,I'm trying to understand your code. What does len(dict1)<2 do please? I know what len does but I couldn't understand the purpose of it in this context